# pid file contains many integers and service won't stop though it starts successfully

Tags: linux, shell

I have written the below code to create a pid file for my spring boot application.

```
    File pid = new File("service.pid");
    pid.deleteOnExit();

    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(BusRouteServiceApplication.class);
    springApplication.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter(pid));
    springApplication.run(args);
```

Still the pid file gets created in the name "app.pid". And I am using the below script to start and stop the spring app.

```
#!/bin/bash

RUN="java -jar service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar --filename=$2"
NAME=app

DATA_FILE=$2

PIDFILE=$NAME.pid
LOGFILE=/tmp/$NAME.log

start() {
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
    if kill -0 $(cat $PIDFILE); then
        echo 'Service already running' >&2
        return 1
    else
        rm -f $PIDFILE
    fi
    fi
    local CMD="$RUN $DATA_FILE &> \"$LOGFILE\" & echo \$!"
    sh -c "$CMD" > $PIDFILE
}

stop() {
    if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ] || ! kill -0 $(cat $PIDFILE); then
    echo 'Service not running' >&2
    return 1
    fi
    kill $(cat $PIDFILE) && rm -f $PIDFILE
}


case $1 in
    start)
    start
    ;;
    stop)
    stop
    ;;
    block)
    start
    sleep infinity
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|block} DATA_FILE"
esac
```

But service is not stopping. I have printed out the value of cat $PIDFILE. At times this is printing process ID + the date. At times it contains a list what looks like a lot of process ids. What am I doing wrong here? How can I correctly stop this spring boot app? I am new to spring. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Get your script checked through shellcheck.net.  `$line` is not set and you could have caught it, among other things. You are writing PIDFILE in current directory and that can be a problem.

Comment: Perhaps would be better to manage PID files _only_ in script.

Comment: @linuxfan how can I do that?

Comment: @codeforester yes that was a mistake. Edited the question. I haven't tried writing to other locations. I'll try and let you know

Comment: "how can I do that". I don't know what `spring` does, and why it needs to have/know a pid file. It seems that the app writes to this file, I think this is not wanted. I thought that the pid file should be exclusive matter of the script starting/stopping the app.